# Run query at specific time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I need to execute the query below in Grafana and filter the returned data at a specific time, starting at 8 in the morning and ending at 11 at night every day.

Query:

```
sum(
  avg_over_time(
    probe_success{
      job=~"Blackbox GETs Middleware Disponibilidade|Blackbox GETs Middleware VerificarPrimeiraCompra"
    }[$__range]
  ) * 100
)/2
```

Example of `probe_success` returns:

```
1 @1691361852.361
1 @1691361972.361
1 @1691362092.361
```

I tried to run it this way:

```
sum(
  avg_over_time(
    probe_success{
      job=~"Blackbox GETs Middleware Disponibilidade|Blackbox GETs Middleware VerificarPrimeiraCompra"
    }[15h] offset 8h
  )
) * 100 / 2
```

and

```
(
  probe_success {job=~"Blackbox GETs Middleware Disponibilidade|Blackbox GETs Middleware VerificarPrimeiraCompra"} == 0
    and on()
  (hour() >= 9 and hour() <= 17)
)[1d:1m]
```

Comment: The last one seems close to what you described. Why it doesn't satisfy you?